# Driver API not working when apply for access

Tags: uber-api

In this page [Uber Drivers Api](https://developer.uber.com/products/drivers) when I apply to get access to api I'm getting nothing from the SEND button by the form. And when I check the network and console I see that status returned fail.

Comment: The form itself says: *Please note that this API is currently only available to a limited set of developers.* so this means that you would need to be granted access / authorization for those APIs. There will be a process where one would be able to secure access.

Comment: The former itself says that but the problem is because the forms buttons is not working, not sending any request and when inspecting in the browser console some errors pop up right after hit the send button.

Comment: I just tried submitting a request via firefox and my submission as verified by the `POST` network call went through. https://ibb.co/rF3h6rZ

Comment: Thank mate, I was using safari and for some reason my POST was returning error code. But anyways when I submitted via firefox everything went well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matheus pointed out, he was using a browser which did not successfully sent the POST command to the server to submit his request.

Ensure that in your browser, through the Developer Tools, the POST command to the Uber API is getting POSTED successfully.

You can refer to a [screenshot from a Firefox](https://ibb.co/rF3h6rZ) post tested for this.